# Why can not separate text lines in Telegram?

Tags: special-characters, telegram, mql4, mql5

I created an EA in MQL4 where I send a text to be displayed as 3 lines of text in Telegram where each line is ended with \n as follows:

```
message = "Line one\n" +
          "Line two\n" +
          "Line three";
```

But somehow, the message are shown in Telegram as 1 single line, concatenating all the 3 lines.
I think \n is not recognized by Telegram. I am not sure what kind of characters should be used to create a line break.
Can anyone provide some help for me on how to separate each lines so it is shown neatly in Telegram message?

Thank you.

Alvin

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `\r\n` to your text instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Has tried, but somehow it does not break the lines

Comment: Can you give feedback of what the result is? What is displayed where the line break should be? Have you tried `\\n` as well?

Comment: The result is the same. The text are concatenated into one line of text:

Line oneLine twoLine three

Comment: if I use \\n, the result is: Line one\nLine two\nLine three. By the way, the sending of text is via WebRequest function. The text are concatenated into the string:   

string url = mBaseUrl+"/bot"+mToken+"/sendMessage?chat_id="+mChatID+"&text="+message;

and then the function call is: returnval=WebRequest("GET",url,mCookie,NULL,timeout,mPost,0,mResult,mHeaders);

Answer (score 0):

```
   string limit = "78.65";
   string tp = "80.45";
   string sl = "71.23";
   
   string msg = StringFormat("BRN SELL|LIMIT: %s|TP: %s|SL: %s", limit, tp, sl);
   StringReplace(msg,"|", "%0A");
```

That's how I do it in MQL5.